# Two sections in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I would like to make an app that kind of looks like this.

[image]

there are plenty of posts about how to make height of uitableviewcell dynamic so that's not a problem for me. The question I have is how are they separating the cells into two columns with different fonts? Is there a tutorial or example how to implement one in uitableview?

Comment: Are you wanting two different columns of table view cells or one column with different types of labels inside of it?

Comment: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: @drop not sure what is the best approach to achieve something as shown above? 1 row with 2 labels or 1 row with 2 columns?

Comment: I would say have one dynamic table view cell with as many labels as you need and then style them as you would like.  Just set the Style on the Table View Cells to Custom and then add in the labels as, and then you can change the font and size on the labels.

Comment: How did they get multiple font colors in same label? see the one on the right

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a link.  I have seen a few diffident ways to do this out there. One is GLTapLabel also http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/ just google around for something that fits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a custom cell with two labels.

Here are the basic steps:

1. Create a new table and a UITableViewController subclass for it.  (I assume that you know how to do this part since you said that you can do variable height rows.)
2. Click on the prototype cell and select the Attributes Inspector.
3. Set your Identifier (Reuse Identifier) to a value.  Let's set it to "TwoLabelCell"
4. Drag two labels onto the prototype cell, and arrange them where you want them.
5. Set the fonts of each label to the way that you want them
6. Set the tag of each of the labels to different values so that you can identify them later.  In this case, let's set the left one to 1000 and the right one to 1001.
7. In your custom class, implement the following methods:

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TwoLabelCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell           = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *leftLabel  = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    UILabel *rightLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];

    // Set the values based on the indexPath.  This is just an example.
    leftLabel.text      = @"409";
    rightLabel.text     = @"Vandals and Alans cross the Pyrenees and appear in Hispania.";
}
```

If you will be interacting with the individual rows a lot, you may want to subclass and have properties for each label.  (I.e cell.yearLabel and cell.descriptionLabel)

Comment: @abhishekkharwar provided a link in his answer to a video showing how to make a custom cell.  I have not watched it, but it may help.  I'll update my answer with a few more details though.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can get this by adding two labels for custom tableviewcell please refer this link [Custom UITableViewCell Using Interface Builder](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/&ei=7eaOUKOjHITXrQfG7YDwAw&usg=AFQjCNGk2oznClItzoMuduKsltU3jRqeKQ&sig2=8z6JnxN9fvrwmA58kwwm0g)